# Volume 00, issue 0

Tags: journals

I have met this in a few articles already: the volume and issue number of the Journal are 00(0). What does it mean? How should I use it in my reference list?

Answer (score 7):

Volume 00 Issue 0 of a journal looks like a placeholder for the actual volume and issue numbers, especially if you're seeing this in a manuscript that is under submission or, as noted by [Anyon](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/126043/volume-00-issue-0/126044?noredirect=1#comment335372_126044), an online preprint made available by the journal prior to publishing.

Comment: Yes, it likely is a placeholder for an "online first" article.